# How to find maximum number of records for a particular key in a table

Tags: oracle11g

I was trying to find which customer has more number of records in a table, i got suggested by RANK function but its not the useful in finding the exact record , so i used this following snippet:

```
select count(customerkey),customerkey 
FROM FILEMAPPERTEMPLATE
group by customerkey;
```

Result :

```
  1 298,254
  1 299,732
  2 246,027
 43 197,053
  1 299,745
  1 299,751
 60 271,623
```

Though i am able to find how many reocrds attributed to a customerkey in the table, I couldn't find the single exact record(after executing the query ) that has maximum record fro a customer. Please help
I want only

60   271,623 as reult

Answer (score 0):

select * from (select count(customerkey) cnt,customerkey 
FROM FILEMAPPERTEMPLATE
group by customerkey order by cnt desc) where rownum<2;